# Count the number of quotes in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to get this to work it keeps returning null.  I need a very simple way to get a count of the number of quotes in a string.

```
var wtf = '"""'
var count = wtf.match(/"/g);
alert(count);
```

This has the same problem.

```
var count = tableitems[i].match(/\"/g);
alert(count);
```

Comment: Your first code example doesn't return `null` as you suggest.

Comment: you code works. what's your question ?

Comment: Split is much faster than using Regex(atleast in chrome). So use split() if it is possible for your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` does not return the count but the matches themselves. You want the length of your matches:

```
var wtf = '"""'
var matches = wtf.match(/"/g);
var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
```

The last line means: "if there are matches count them, if not return zero"

Comment: is this actually a line of code? ---- var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;   ---

Comment: sure, it's a ternary operator, see edit

Comment: count=  matches&& matches.length || 0; also works, and is slightly faster, as is count=(matches || "").length;

Comment: @dandavis yes, but also slightly less readable in my opinion. in the end just a matter of taste because the performance differences won't be measurable in most cases

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `count` is the array of matches. To see how many there are, do

```
alert(count ? count.length : 0) // count is null if there are no matches
```

In case you were thinking of making the switch (:P), coffeescript has a nice way to deal with this type of situation:

```
wtf = '"""'
count = wtf.match(/"/g)?.length;
```

If there are no matches, count will be `undefined`, otherwise it will be the number of matches.

Comment: I would use `alert( count ? count.length : 0 )`, since if there are no matches it'll indeed return null.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like that:

```js
const countDoubleQuotes = wtf => wtf.split('"').length - 1;

console.log(countDoubleQuotes('"')); // expected 1
console.log(countDoubleQuotes('"Hello world"')); // expected 2
console.log(countDoubleQuotes('"""')); // expected 3
console.log(countDoubleQuotes('_"_')); // expected 1
```

Comment: string splitting is much faster than using a regexp, this is a good solution.

Comment: This is wrong if " is at the end of the string. In this case we have n that is equal to the number of double quotes - 1

Comment: Are you sure? I mean really sure? Have you tested it? I've made it a runnable snippet to convince yourself